# Java, while-loop, counter does not exit loop

Tags: java, while-loop, counter

I am pretty much of a beginner in Java and I cannot figure out following problem. I want this code to generate random numbers between 0-2 (which is working fine) and add this to int A, B, C, D until the sum of A+B+C+D has reached 4. I tried to solve this with a counter (called 'zaehler'). The while loop does not stop when the counter has  reached the 4! I really can't figure it out - maybe someone has some advice? Thanks in advance!

```
public void levelUp()
{
    int zaehler = 0; 
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;
    while(zaehler <= 4)
    {
        int randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3); 
        A += randomInt1;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt1;

        System.out.println("randomInt1 = " + randomInt1);
        System.out.println("A = " + A);
        System.out.println("Zaehler = " + zaehler);

        int randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        B += randomInt2;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt2;

        System.out.println("randomInt2 = " + randomInt2);
        System.out.println("B = " + B);
        System.out.println("Zaehler = " + zaehler);

        int randomInt3 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        C += randomInt3;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt3;

        System.out.println("randomInt3 = " + randomInt3);
        System.out.println("C = " + C);
        System.out.println("Zaehler =" + zaehler);

        int randomInt4 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        D += randomInt4;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt4;

        System.out.println("randomInt4 = " + randomInt4);
        System.out.println("D = " + D);
        System.out.println("Zaehler = " + zaehler);
    }    
}   

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    TestRandom test = new TestRandom();
    test.levelUp(); 
}
```

Comment: You have `while(zaehler <= 4)` so it's not going to stop until it reaches a number >= 5

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't stop"?

Comment: Are you trying to exit the loop as soon as 4 is reached? i.e. If `A` is `2` and `B` is `2` do you want to exit the loop without changing `C` and `D`? If so, use `break`.

Comment: What happens you are at 3 and then the next random number is 2? As a result you would be at 5. How to handle that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop. If you want to stop loops as you wish, on your own control, it's better than while.

```
for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){
//Enter your loop here
//To create a random between 0 and 2:
int random= 0+(int)(Math.random()*2));
}
```

I don't know if you understand for loops, this creates an int called i (like your zaehler) that increases in 1 everytime the loops finish. This loop will continue until `int i` reaches 4.

Comment: He wants to stop looping when the sum of A, B, C and D is >= 4

Comment: Then your code must work, but is not a good practise to use breaks in while loops.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice! I tried out John Pauls solution, already looks much better. The problem now is only that sometimes the sum of A, B, C, D is still 5 and not 4. Here is an example output from console: randomInt1 = 2
A = 2
Zaehler = 2
randomInt2 = 0
B = 0
Zaehler = 2
randomInt3 = 1
C = 1
Zaehler =3
randomInt4 = 2
D = 2
Zaehler = 5
FinalA = 2
FinalB = 0
FinalC = 1
FinalD = 2
5

Comment: Then use an else{} in the end to repeat the loop or the show another answer

Comment: Don't think there is anything wrong with break statements.

Comment: @CodeIsland the reason for the 5 is because of the scenario I commented before. How is it supposed to be handled?

Comment: If the body of your loop spans several screen lengths and has multiple nested sub-blocks, yes, you could easily forget that some code won't be executed after the break. If, however, the loop is short and to the point, the purpose of the break statement should be obvious.

If a loop is getting too big, use one or more well-named function calls within the loop instead. The only real reason to avoid doing so is for processing bottlenecks.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is but I will rewrite it without break statements.

Comment: I mean, there's nothing wrong in that example, but to avoid future problems in other loops, it's better to avoid them, nothing else. Have fun guys!

Answer (score 0):

This will stop at 4 or 5. If you don't want 5 at all then you need to update your question how to handle that scenario.

```
public void levelUp()
{
    int zaehler = 0;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;
    while (zaehler <= 4)
    {
        int randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        A += randomInt1;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt1;

        if (zaehler >= 4)
            break;

        int randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        B += randomInt2;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt2;

        if (zaehler >= 4)
            break;

        int randomInt3 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        C += randomInt3;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt3;

        if (zaehler >= 4)
            break;

        int randomInt4 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        D += randomInt4;
        zaehler = zaehler + randomInt4;

        if (zaehler >= 4)
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("A = " + A);
    System.out.println("B = " + B);
    System.out.println("C = " + C);
    System.out.println("D = " + D);

    System.out.println(zaehler);
}
```